Fastest root-finding algorithm for specific sine function
I'm trying to find an algorithm which will tell me any root of the function
sin(πx)² + sin(π(323/x))²
With this function I can very confidently isolate an interval in which one of these roots would exist, however there is no change in the signs in front of the function values, which is why algorithms like bisection don't work. Furthermore there are a couple of trivial roots like 1 and 323, these I'm not interested in. Is there any good algorithm to find roots on functions like these?

Surely you'd be better off asking on the Math stack exchange?

Honestly, might be. Am primarily a programmer so this was the first place I thought about hahahahhaha. Will try tho, ty

Are you looking for real or complex solutions?

If you are looking for fastest method, you can solve the equation manually:
sin(pi * x)^2 + sin(pi * 323 / x)^2 = 0

If we are looking for real (not complex) roots, we can say that each square is at least 0 and that's why to have sum of squares be equal to 0 each square must be 0:
sin(pi * x)^2 = 0
sin(pi * 323 / x)^2 = 0

or
x - integer number (from 1st equation)
323 / x - integer number (from 2nd equation)

so far so good, we want to get all integer divisors of 323, they are
-323, -19, -17, -1, 1, 17, 19, 323
And we can get O(1) time and space solution
return { -323, -19, -17, -1, 1, 17, 19, 323 };

In general case
sin(pi * A * x)^ 2 + sin(pi * B / x)^2 = 0

for x to be a root we should have both A * x and B / x to be integers. Or if we put y = A * x then y is an integer divisor of A * B.
Algorithm

Find all integer divisors of A * B (both positive and negative), ys
Roots xs are xi = yi / A

In our case A = 1, B = 323 we have A * B = 323, divisors are y = {-323, -19, ..., 323}, roots are x = y / A = y / 1 = y = {-323, -19, ..., 323}
